# c# how to check if an object is of a certain type

Tags: c#, arrays, object, xna, equals

I am just wondering what the process is for checking the object type of something.

Basically I have an array of parent objects and I want to check if one of those objects is of a particular child type.

more specifically, I want to check if an array of GameScreen objects contains a GameScreen object of type GameplayScreen.

```
        GameScreen[] screens = mScreenManager.GetScreens();

        // loop through array and check if the object equals gameplayscreen


        }
```

Comment: This is almost always the wrong thing to be doing.  If you're going to have a collection of parent objects, the parent type should have whatever members you need to use for every object in this collection.  You should rely on polymorphism such that each item acts appropriately *without you needing to know what its type is*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the type using [`is` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) like:

```
if(screens[0] is GamePlayScreen)
```

Or if you just need `GamePlayScreen` type objects from your array you can use :

```
GamePlayScreen[] items = screens.OfType<GamePlayScreen>().ToArray();
```

See: [Enumerable.OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It uses `System.Linq`

Comment: is it possible that in GameScreens type of array GamePlayScreen type coud exist, i am unable to understand your logic, please if you explain it for me

Comment: but your answer is great learned a new thing..hope i remember it i my mind..:)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `is` keyword when you want to check a type.

```
class Foo {}
class SuperFoo : Foo {}

bool IsSuperFoo(Foo foo)
{
    if (Foo is SuperFoo) return true;
    return false;
}
```

You can do the same for your GamePlayScreen.